# Working with two windows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am new to programming specially objective c.

I have a two windows in MainMenu.xib.

1st window (with webview) is launching when i run my application.
I am able to launch 2nd window (with a text field and save button) from top menu.

I have specified a default URL as "www.google.com" for first launch.

Now i want to configure URL by putting it in textfield on 2nd window. Whenever i click "SAVE" 1st window should refresh with newly given URL.

How is it possible and how i can connect action button "SAVE" that it impact on 1st window.

Here is my code

**AppDelegate.h contains**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webview;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *urlString;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
**And my AppDelegate.m contains**

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize webview;
@synthesize urlString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
    [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];

}



-(IBAction)save{
[[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString.stringValue]]];

}

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have 2 object controller or one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the **Save Menu** and Ctrl+Drag to your class.

Set the action to your `save` or create a new one.

(Either call your method from IBAction method created by XCode or put your code there.)

[image]

Comment: (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification   this will launch my default window with webview, how i will force it to load window with configured URL from secondary window. Even i followed your given steps but  i don't understand to load webview window with new URL.

Comment: in the saveAction, you need to read textField or URL and then send this to your first window to the webview and call reload etc

Comment: ok thanks Anoop, Actually i am also new on this forum. 100 votes for u :-)